# Deploying to a camunda process engine

Tags: camunda

I want to achieve the following: Have a camunda-7.3 prepackaged distro running with the rest-api. Have another server, lets say a wildfly server, running with a vaadin application deployed.

From within in the vaadin application, I want to create a cmmn case and deploy/start it in the process engine. Then from from within the vaadin aplication i want to display some sort of tasklist to complete the active tasks.

The question here is: Is this setup even possible? If so, how to deploy a new cmmn case to the engine?

I checked the tutorials from the camunda webpage but each tutorial only deploys the cmmn cases (and bpmn processes) by deploying another webapp to the server hosting the camunda engine. On the other hand, the camunda references cleary state, that it is possible to have a standalone camunda engine running.

Anyone has any thoughts on the topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For deploying both BPMN processes and CMMN cases you can

1) Login

```
curl -w "\n" --cookie-jar cookie.txt \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -d "username=$USERNAME" \
  -d "password=$PASSWORD" \
  $API/admin/auth/user/default/login/cockpit
```

2) Deploy (see http://docs.camunda.org/latest/api-references/rest/#deployment-post-deployment)

```
curl -w "\n" --cookie cookie.txt \
  -H "Accept: application/json" \
  -F "deployment-name=rest-test" \
  -F "enable-duplicate-filtering=false" \
  -F "deploy-changed-only=false" \
  -F "process.bpmn=@$PROCESS" \
  $API/engine/engine/default/deployment/create
```

Comment: Yeah, I already found that part of the REST API but it seems that this will only work for BPMN processes and not for CMMN cases. My rep was too low to add a new tag to the question. Maybe it was that obvious that I want to work with CMMN and not with BPMN.

Comment: Okay, I got it now. The /deployment/create API can be used for both, BPMN and CMMN definitions! I used the other CMMN REST-APIs a little bit wrong. I had to call create case instace instead of manual start case execution.

Comment: Thx for sharing your experience with 7.3 - feature seems to be unchanged